# Magento - Update stating customer & sales info in database, from live site

Tags: sql, magento, export, upgrade

I have a magento 1.8.1 CE live right now. I have been building a 1.9.x update to this site. I used the existing 1.8.1 database as a base for this new install/update.

Since then, some time has passed and the live site has new customer/sales info that I want to bring into the staging/development installation before switching and making the staging live.

I'm under the impression that the customer and sales information live on separate tables from product, cms, etc.. I have not made any product or attribute changes - other than those installed by very few extensions.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I'm currently importing all the customer_, sales_ and salesrule_ tables from the 1.8 to new 1.9 - i'm expecting a fail, but we'll see how it goes.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you bring in customer/sales data into a development/staging environment?  Why does it matter?  If you are planning on pushing the dev/staging DB to production that's a tremendously bad idea for oh so many reasons.

Comment: i'm trying to get the staging database caught up with the changes on the live site, which have only been new sales & customer info - all products and other items are unchanged.

I was able to do an export of all customer_, sales_, and salesrule_ tables and the database seems to be working fine - what errors should I be looking for?